# Autolisp json_encode json_decode

Tags: lisp, autolisp

Does anybody have json_encode / json_decode functions for lisp, on Autocad?

I can read/write data from/to file, but it would be a great help to encode it to JSON; then I can link everything to javascript/php/mysql ...

Comment: I guess, it shouldn't be hard to port the Common Lisp version. Something like [yason](https://github.com/hanshuebner/yason/)

Comment: Please note that **"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."**